# Validating a proof found online on the Zariski continuity of morphisms between affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading a proof of the fact that if $F: V \to W$ is a morphism between affine varieties, then $F$ is continuous with repsect to the Zariski topology, but they are seeminlgy skipping some steps and I don't know how the following is true.

> Since any morphism $V \to W$ extends to a morphism $\Bbb A^n \to \Bbb A^m$, we may assume  that $V= \Bbb A^n$ and $W= \Bbb A^m$. Let $F_1, \dots F_m \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ be the component functions of $F$. Consider an arbitrary closed subset $Z=\Bbb V(g_1, \dots , g_k) \subset \Bbb A^m$, where $g_1, \dots, g_k \in k[y_1, \dots, y_m]$. Then it follows that $$F^{-1}(Z)=\Bbb V(g_1(f_1, \dots,f_m), \dots,g_k(f_1, \dots ,f_m))$$ hence $F^{-1}(Z)$ is closed and $F$ continuous.

They seem to be pulling some of these results out of thin air. How come it "follows" that $F^{-1}(Z)=\Bbb V(g_1(f_1, \dots,f_m), \dots,g_k(f_1, \dots ,f_m))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,
$$F^{-1}(Z)=\{P\in \mathbb{A}^n\mid F(P)\in Z\}\\
=\{P\in \mathbb{A}^n\mid (F_1(P),\dots,F_m(P))\in V(g_1,\dots,g_k)\},$$
and
$$V(g_1,\dots,g_k)=\{Q\in \mathbb{A}^m\mid g_1(Q)=\dots=g_k(Q)=0\}.$$
Hence,
$$F(P)=(F_1(P),\dots,F_m(P))\in V(g_1,\dots,g_k)\iff g_1(F(P))=\dots=g_k(F(P))=0$$
which is equivalent to $P\in V(g_1(F_1,\dots,F_m),\dots,g_k(F_1,\dots,F_m)).$